# Why is increasing the font-size of <span> disproportionate compared to the rest?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, font-size

I want to increase the following text to font-size: 3em, both "Some" and "text". When I apply the following:

```css
* {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.foo {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="foo"><span>Some</span> text</div>
</div>
```

the size of "Some" within `<span>` increases at a much higher rate than "text".  Why does this happen and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Use `rem` units instead of `em`. Instead of setting font with `*` selector, you should set font for `body`.

Comment: in your example some is smaller than text, so probably you have more CSS involved?

Comment: The "Some" text uses 10px as defined bu the `*` rule. It is only the text content directly on `.foo` div that gets the `3em` because that is the only element that is not overridden by the font-size specified in `*`. See the answers below for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` selector matches all elements. Rules defined on this (`*`) selector take precedence over rules defined on parent elements.

So even though, by default, `font-size` is inherited, the font-size on `.foo` doesn't affect the font-size on the child, `span`.

You could read up on `*`, the universal selector - specifically about when to use it.

A default `font-size` is usually something you want to define on the `html` element. Which would solve your problem:

```
html {  font-size: 10px;  }
.foo {  font-size: 3em;  }
```

This way, the font size of `span`, inherited from `.foo`, takes precedence over the `font-size` inherited from the `html`.
As a result of the above code, text inside the `div` with the class `.foo` and text inside `span` will have the same value (3em), and the same computed value (3 times 10px).

If you did:

```
html {  font-size: 10px;  }
.foo {  font-size: 3em;  }
span {  font-size: 3em;  }
```

Span would still have the value of 3em, but the computed value would be 10px * 3 * 3 (90px), 3 times larger, than the font size of `.foo`. This is, because em is relative to the `font-size` of the parent.

Comment: My experience with the increase in the font-size was that the text "Some" within the <span> became bigger than "text" which was set at 3em.  So *selector didn't override the .foo class.  It rather amplified it.

Comment: Because of the inheritance of nested elements regarding the `em` size, it is better to use `rem`, wich is relative to the font size on the top element, and not the closest parent. In most cases this is the desired behaviour (and less confusing).

Answer (score 3):

Because the `*`selector also selects *everything*, including `span` elements, except if there is another CSS rule overriding it. So the contents of the `foo` DIV are 3em (= 3 x the 10px), whereas the `span` in it is reset to 10px by that `*` rule.

If you define the 10px size for `div` instead of `*`, the whole thing looks different:

```css
div {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.foo {
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Font size defined for DIVs</div>
  <div class="foo"><span>Some</span> text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If the <span> is reset by the *selector which is 10px, doesn't that mean the text within <span> should be smaller than the rest, which is 3 x 10px?

Comment: @Kevvv In your example code where you have defined `* { font-size: 10px; }` -YES exaclty. Here in @Johannes answer, he has removed the `*` selector, and define it on `div` indstead. Actually it would be better to define the default on `body`, because in this case you will get the same problem for other divs nested inside `.foo`.

Comment: @Kevvv Yes - in the example in your question, the situation is exactly as you wrote in your comment: the text in `span` is 10px, since `*` applies to it and overrides the `3em` of the `.foo` class selector

Answer (score -2):

You should use consistant font measurements throughout your page. If you are using `px`, stick with `px`. If you are using `em`, or `rem`, stick with that. Right now you are showing two different measurements (which is most likely the problem):

```
* {  font-size: 10px;  }
.foo {  font-size: 3em;  }
```

Since `pixels` and `em` display differently, change it to:

```
* {  font-size: 10em;  }
.foo {  font-size: 3em;  }
```

Or, change it so both font-size elements use `px`. Your choice.